# where condition with HasOne laravel

Tags: laravel, has-one

In login model I have implement relation with picture table

```
function picture () {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Picture');
}
```

Now I want data where Picture.picture_status = 1 and User.user_status = 1

```
Login::with('picture')->where('picture_status', 1)->where('user_status',1);
```

but where condition is not working with picture table, how can i implement and condition on both table

Answer (score 15):

```php
class Login extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    function picture () {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Picture', 'id', 'user_id')->where('picture_status', 1)->where('user_status',1)->first();
    }
}
```

You can call like this;

```php
$usersWithProfilePictures = Login::with('picture')->get();
```

Comment: There's no need to append `first()` at the end.

Comment: If you add `first()` at the end, `$login->picture` will return `null`. Since you treat `picture` as a method, not a model property. You should remove the `first()`, and then you can call it just like model property, `$login->picture`.

Answer (score 9):

This should do it:

```
Login::with(['picture' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('picture_status', 1)->where('user_status',1);
}])->get();
```

Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify additional query constraints for the eager loading query
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 2):

```
class Login extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    function picture () {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Picture', 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    ................
    public function myF(){
         self::with('picture')->where('picture_status', 1)->where('user_status',1)->get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone still stumbles upon this problem. The best way to retrieve correct records would be to use Laravel Query Builder with join:

```
$logins = DB::table('logins')
            ->join('pictures', 'logins.id', '=', 'pictures.login_id')
            ->select('logins.*', 'pictures.status')
            ->where('logins.status', 1)
            ->where('pictures.status', 1)
            ->get();
```

You can learn more at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ofMany Laravel function
wich means the Model has one of many

```
function picture()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Picture', 'id', 'user_id')->ofMany(
        function ($query) {
            return $query->where('picture_status', 1)->where('user_status', 1);
        });
}
```