# subquery in laravel - with()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm making a query using the following line:

```
$items = $this->model->with('subCategory')->get();
```

But I want to put a query inside the `with()` method, because I just want to get the items from `with()` where the status is equal to 0.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38371708/6569866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called eagarload constraints, you can achieve your result using a closure

For example

```
$items = $this->model->with(['subCategory'=>function($q){
    $q->whereId('5');
    //or any other valid query builder method.
}])->get();
```

Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 2):

There is an "eager loading" in L5 documentation. [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

```
$items = $this->model->with(['subCategory' => function ($query) {
  $query->where('status', 0); }])->get();
```